# How do i get a Vue Compsable to only work with a single target item in a list

Tags: vue.js, composable

I have a composable that takes a function and calls the function upon the long-press of a component that uses it(the composable). however, if I use it in a list of components, it seems to call the function on all the components instead of only the component/item I long-pressed in the list. How do I make it so that the function is only called on the target component/item?

The composable(/composables/useLongPress)

```
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue';

const longPress = (binding) => {
  const isHeld = ref(false);
  const activeHoldTimer = ref(null);

  const onHoldStart = () => {
    isHeld.value = true;
    activeHoldTimer.value = setTimeout(() => {
      if (isHeld.value) {
        binding();
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  const onHoldEnd = () => {
    isHeld.value = false;
    if (activeHoldTimer.value) {
      clearTimeout(activeHoldTimer.value);
    }
  };
  onMounted(() => {
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', onHoldStart);
    window.addEventListener('touchstart', onHoldStart);
    window.addEventListener('click', onHoldEnd);
    window.addEventListener('mouseout', onHoldEnd);
    window.addEventListener('touchend', onHoldEnd);
    window.addEventListener('touchcancel', onHoldEnd);
  });

  onUnmounted(() => {
    window.removeEventListener('mousedown', onHoldStart);
    window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onHoldStart);
    window.removeEventListener('click', onHoldEnd);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseout', onHoldEnd);
    window.removeEventListener('touchend', onHoldEnd);
    window.removeEventListener('touchcancel', onHoldEnd);
  });
};

export default longPress;
```

The child component/item (/InvoiceListItem.vue)

```
<template>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 py-4">
    <div>
      <p class="text-lg font-medium">{{ invoice.client }}</p>
      <p class="mt-2 text-xs font-light text-gray-500">Due {{ invoice.due }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-end">
      <p class="text-lg font-bold">${{ invoice.amount }}</p>
      <base-pill
        :variant="invoice.status"
        :label="capitalize(invoice.status)"
        class="mt-2"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import BasePill from '../../BasePill.vue';
import { capitalize } from '../../../utils';
import useLongPress from '../../../composables/useLongPress';

const props = defineProps({
  invoice: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
});

const log = () => console.log(props.invoice);
useLongPress(log);
</script>

<style lang="postcss" scoped></style>
```

The parent/list of components (/InvoiceList.vue)

```
<template>
  <div class="divide-y">
    <div v-for="(invoice, index) in invoices" :key="index">
      <invoice-list-item :invoice="invoice" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import InvoiceListItem from './InvoiceListItem.vue';

defineProps({
  invoices: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => [],
  },
});
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

when I long press on one invoice item I am supposed to log the value of the one item but instead, I get the value of all items in the list

Comment: Any chance you could create a *runnable* [mcve]? Note codesandbox allows [importing](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) local projects using their CLI utility.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Here is a [link](https://replit.com/@Benjamin-ochien/stackoverflowcomquestions74153513#src/router/index.js). You will notice if I click and hold on one item it console logs data for all items instead of just the one.